# No video skype found

Tags: apt, command-line

I've been looking for Skype for Ubuntu 12.04 and all I can do with the downloads I've found is Skype without video call, just voice call. Please help.

Comment: Ubuntu 32bit or 64bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

skype 4.0 isn't updated in ubuntu software database, please download appropriate deb file from  [here](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/get-skype/on-your-computer/linux/)